# Having problems updating the database of a Django project after HTML changes

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I am trying to write a Django app that has a counter that increases on a button press, and decreases on another. I want this to save to the database (ideally) on each change. I have been able to update the HTML file from a separate JavaScript file by calling a js function via onclick and getting the data via JSON.parse, and changing the number with counter.innerHTML = new_number. However, I'm stumped on how to proceed. From what I've found Ajax seems to be my only option, but I am not sure how to get started with integrating it into my code. Below is a part of my html file and my JavaScript file. Any help would be fantastic

Hunt.html

```
<div class="column">
      <div class="card"
        style="width: auto;border-style:solid; border-color:black; padding: 5px; background-color:rgb(50, 50, 50);">
        <div class="card-body" style="color:rgb(172,238,239); background-color:rgb(50, 50, 50); ">
          <h5 id = "Encounters" class="card-title" style="font-size: 36px;">Encounters:
            {{currentHunt.count}}</h5>
        </div>
        <button onclick = "incrementCounter()" class="button" id="my_button">+</button>
        
        <button class="button1">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

main.js

```
var count = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('count').textContent);
var increment = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('increment').textContent);

function incrementCounter() {
  var counter = document.getElementById('Encounters');
  count += increment;
  var encounters = "Encounters: ";
  counter.innerHTML = encounters.concat(count);
}
```